# How to find the possible combinations of 13 cards in poker?

Tags: probability

From a standard 52 cards deck, given 13 random cards, I'm trying to find the possible combinations to be put in 3 slots (the total number of combinations as well as the list of combinations itself)

First slot is 5 cards

Second slot is 5 cards

Third slot is 3 cards

No ordering in each slot.  (A, B, C, D, E) is the same as (C, D, A, B, E)

How would I go about approaching this? Thank you

Comment: Are the first and second slots distinguishable?

Comment: @TiwaAina yes they are.

Comment: In order to actually list the combinations, you need an algorithm to generate all the subsets of $13$ objects taken $3$ at a time.  Computer scientists have developed several such algorithms.  For example, see section 7.2.1.3 of "The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 4A, Combinatorial Algorithms, Part 1" by Donald Knuth.  Alternatively, if you just want results and don't care where they come from, if you are a Python programmer you could use the itertools.combinations() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say "first," "second," and "third," it seems to me that the slots are distinguishable.

We can put $5$ cards (out of the $13$ we start with) in the first slot in $\binom{13}{5}$ ways.

We can put $5$ cards (out of the $13-5=8$ we now have) in the second slot in $\binom{8}{5}$ ways.

We can put the remaining $3$ cards in the third slot in $\binom{3}{3}=1$ way.

Put this together for a total of $\binom{13}{5}\binom{8}{5}\binom{3}{3}=72072$ possible combinations.

This is *given* the fact that the 13 cards have already been chosen. If we have to  choose the 13 from a deck and *then* distribute among the slots, we would multiply our result by $\binom{52}{13}$ (and end up with $45,766,697,267,491,200$), since there are $\binom{52}{13}$ ways to choose $13$ cards out of a set of $52$.

Addendum: Here's some context for that last number. If you wanted a file with every combination of cards in slots (using Ks to denote King of Spades, for instance), you would need over one [exabyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exabyte) of storage for that one file!

Comment: lol 1 exabyte. Thank you for the information. :D

Comment: any idea how to print out the results for the 72072? i see there would be three for loops and a lot of lists

Comment: @JackSmother I'm not a very good programmer (I only know basic Python and Java). Using Python, I would make a set of lists containing every size-5 subset of your deck-of-thirteen (e.g. deck13 = ["Ah", "2h",...,"Ks"]). Then, for each of these lists, I would make a set of every possible slot2 based on the cards in the lists I'm iterating over. Then, I would make Cartesian product of the set of slot1 lists and their corresponding set of slot2 lists. Finally, in each of the lists, I would append a list of the 3 cards left over. I recommend going on StackOverflow for a better implementation.